# Net core app as Windows Service return error 404 in web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I recently created a Windows Service for my Net Core app based on Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#current-directory-and-content-root)

Everything runs fine and the service is running, but when i visit the web page on localhost:5000, this appears:
[image]

My startup looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true,
                    ConfigFile = "webpack.dev.js"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.Use(async (_context, next) =>
            {
                if (_context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("access_token", out var token))
                {
                    _context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
                }
                await next.Invoke();

            });
...
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
        });
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
 var esServicio = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
        if (esServicio)
        {
            string pathExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var pathContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathExe);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathContentRoot);
        }
        IWebHostBuilder builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(x => x != "--console").ToArray());
        var host = builder.Build();
        if (esServicio)
        {
            host.RunAsCustomService();
        }
        else
        {
            host.Run();
        }
```

I use Vue in the Front End app, and combined with my back end; when deploy in IIS or with `dotnet` command, everything works. 
Someone has an idea of ​​what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a [404](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) error means resource not found. Something like a ~/ or / might be needed. Use trial and error with the css files until you find out where the files are. For instance in  .net core the wwwroot folder is the root folder so anything in there will be relative to root; wwwroot/css/site.css is accessed from your webpage as /css/site.css.